# How do I add an NSString to NSMutableData?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledata

I cannot figure out how to add my NSString to an NSMutableData structure

this is what I want to achieve, below is hardcoded and works, you can see the number string is what I want to replace with dynamic data from a helper function I have.

```
NSMutableData *commands = [NSMutableData data];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n" length:sizeof("\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n") - 1];
```

I tried constructing an NSString that would mimic the above exactly as follows

```
NSString *trNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20\" \"%@\x1e\r\n\"", [NWTillHelper getCurrentOrderNumber]];
```

But this cannot be added to the NSMutableData construct, I tried as below

```
[commands appendBytes:(__bridge const void * _Nonnull)(trNo) length:sizeof("\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n") - 1];
```

How can I create an appendBytes construct in such a way that I can insert my NSString into it and get it to be dynamic?

---- Further clarification -----

I am using the NSData structure to send to a printer

for example the following is the code to cut the label

```
 // Cut the paper
    [commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x64\x02" length:sizeof("\x1b\x64\x02") - 1];
```

This is the command for making the text aligned center

```
// Alignment (Center)
    [commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x1d\x61\x01" length:sizeof("\x1b\x1d\x61\x01") - 1];
```

As you can see these are plain Hex commands and they work fine as is

The problem I am having is that the command to print a barcode includes a dynamic string in the middle of all the HEX code and I cannot figure out how to get an NSString into the middle of this HEX code.

This is the command to print a barcode, where the barcode contains the numbers 09258384394951, as you can see those are hardcoded below. This code works fine, the printer prints the barcode correctly but the problem is that I cannot hardcode the numbers/characters 09258384394951 I need that to be a variable of some sort and this is where I am stuck.

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n" length:sizeof("\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n") - 1];
```

Comment: You can try convert the string to bytes first. NSData *strByte = [trNo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Doesn't work, but printing trio, shows me the following, maybe I am not escaping right?  trNo= "b " "1-20170522141541

Comment: tried escaping some more but still don't work NSString *trNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"\\x1b\\x62\\x06\\x02\\x02\\x20\\\" \"%@\\x1e\\r\\n\\\"", [NWTillHelper getCurrentOrderNumber]];

Comment: @GeneCode: In this case UTF-8 is a very bad solution, because Matt inserts always bytes in his string. If he would insert a byte greater than 127 he would get a multibyte sequence. `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` should be a better choice.

Comment: NSString *trNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"\\x1b\\x62\\x06\\x02\\x02\\x20\\\" \"%@\\x1e\\r\\n\\\"", [NWTillHelper getCurrentOrderNumber]];
    NSData *strByte = [trNo dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]; still don't work

Comment: the new escaping shows me the string is correct now 2017-05-22 14:25:57.900639 NWMobileTill[8796:2654546] trNo= "\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20\" "1-20170522142547\x1e\r\n\"

Comment: Do you really have to work with nsdata? A suggestion: is it plausible for you to convert everything in string, work with that (append/etc), and then change the resulting str to nsdata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the data in 3 steps:

```
NSMutableData *commands = [NSMutableData data];
NSData *orderNumber = [@"09258384394951" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  // example of order number converted to NSData
[commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "" length:sizeof("\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "") - 1];  
[commands appendData:orderNumber];  
[commands appendBytes:"\x1e\r\n" length:sizeof("\x1e\r\n") - 1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[commands appendData:[trNo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: This prints the actual string, as is, I guess the printer expects byte converted data? isn't that what the appendBytes does?

Comment: Oh, are you kinda trying to print hexadecimal string to nsdata?

Comment: Yes I am trying to create an nsdata string that looks exactly that the one in my question but that one is hard coded, I simply want to be able to make it dynamic

Comment: So you basically want to input the "hexadecimal" code straight into the nsmutabledata? so when you use something like "hexdump" on the file, it will show the same hex string? kinda?

Comment: I want to do exactly this, [commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n" length:sizeof("\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n") - 1]; but change the 09258384394951 for a variable

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite following

Comment: The line in my comment above works fine, it prints a barcode instead of 09258384394951, so that command structure works, but of course the string 09258384394951 is hardcoded in my appendBytes structure, all I want is to be able to replace 09258384394951 in the above line of code (which works) with a variable so I can print different barcodes to the printer.

Comment: So you want to "edit" already set NSMutableData, like delete its characters?

Comment: not  really edit I am creating the string from scratch, so assume an empty NSMutableData, and I need to build a structure that looks exactly like this, [commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n" length:sizeof("\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" "09258384394951\x1e\r\n") - 1]; how would I build that when the number 09258384394951 is held in a NSString and cannot be hardcoded like above?

Comment: so you want this exact string in a nsmutabledata "\x1b\x62\x06\x02\x02\x20" or its values?

Comment: The exact string

Comment: If you want the exact string including \x as NSMutableData then in front of each \ and another \ eg. \\x, that will tell the string to ignore the \ in front of the x

Comment: /Users/mdouhan/Documents/dev/NWMobileTill/NWMobileTill/StdUK.m:511:27: Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'NSData *' to C pointer type 'const void * _Nonnull' requires a bridged cast, I get this when trying to add my NSData, I am sorry This really has me beat

Comment: Because your using appendBytes: not appendData: